# Custom Datagrid OnKeyDown check IsEnabled Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I have a data grid with Static Data and two of the items are disabled. The only issue is with Silverlight when using the arrow keys to navigate thru the data grid items the disabled items also get focused on.

I have created a custom data grid class and referenced it in the XAML, and then when using the OnKeyDown event I check for IsEnabled True or False. but so far it is not getting the correct values and I think it is because Where I set the IsEnabled status I am referencing the default Datagrid class?

**CustomDataGrid**

```
public class CustomGrid : DataGrid
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(IsEnabled != false)
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
```

**Xaml**

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="local:CustomGrid">
            <Setter Property="RowStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding enabled}"/> //CheckIsEnabled Value
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>...
```

```
<local:CustomGrid x:Name="McDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}"/>
```

**List Data**

```
 private List<Model> Data()
        {
            list.Add(new Model(1, "Test", "1", true));
            list.Add(new Model(2, "Ger", "2", true));
            list.Add(new Model(3, "dsg", "3", true));
            list.Add(new Model(4, "Hd", "4", false));
            list.Add(new Model(5, "TeHRFdgst", "5", false));
            return list;
        }

        public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public bool _enabled;
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Prop { get; set; }
            public bool enabled
            {
                get { return _enabled; }

                set
                {
                    _enabled = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("enabled");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public Model(int id, string name, string prop, bool isenabled)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                Prop = prop;
                enabled = isenabled;

            }

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

When I change this `<Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">` part with `"local:CustomGrid"` my entire grid just go blank not to sure why.

Is there any advice on how to accomplish this or maybe a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class CustomGrid : DataGrid
{
    private List<Model> models;
    public CustomGrid()
    {
        Loaded += (s,e) => models = ItemsSource as List<Model>;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (models == null)
            return;

        Model model = CurrentItem as Model;
        if (model == null)
            return;

        int index = models.IndexOf(model);
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Down:
                //is the next model disabled?
                if (index < models.Count - 1 && !models[index + 1].enabled)
                    e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Key.Up:
                if (index > 0 && !models[index - 1].enabled)
                    e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="local:CustomGrid">
            <Setter Property="RowStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding enabled}"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <local:CustomGrid x:Name="McDataGrid" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks I thought the fix would be Xaml based but very simple.